# How to save and reuse outputs of different steps of synthesis in Design Compiler?

Tags: synthesis

Is it possible to save outputs of different steps of synthesis in Design Compiler and load them later? For example, is it possible to do `analyze`, save the output of that, and use the saved output during next session in order to save some time and continue where I left off? Is the same thing possible for other commands such as `elaborate`, etc.?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to save and/or load Design Compiler database at different stages of synthesis. Synopsys has *DDC* format to carry both design and constraint information. Files in this format are not human readable, but very useful.

The following example saves the database after elaboration.

```
analyze <bla_bla>
elaborate <bla_bla>
write_file -format ddc -output mydb_1.ddc
```

This example loads the saved database and saves again after compile.

```
read_ddc mydb_1.ddc
compile_ultra
write_file -format ddc -output mydb_2.ddc
```